# Can't make h1 position properly

Tags: html, css

This is my html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<img height="150px" width="150px" src="logo.jpg">
<h1>Silver Hills</h1>
<h5>Strive and succeed</h5>
</div>
<div id="navbar">
</body>
</html>
```

and this is my css

```
#wrapper {
background:-moz-linear-gradient(top,white,yellow 10%,crimson 85%);
height:30%;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
}

img {
margin-top:2%;
}

h1, h5 {
display:inline;
}
```

But how do I get the h1 and h5 elements to align vertically side by side vertical center with the img and in the div(linear gradient)

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Comment: *sidenote:* 0 has no unit in CSS. no need to add `px` after `0`. HTML attribute `height` and `width` has no unit either. And you have a stray `<div id="lbar">`.

Comment: heres a bin: http://jsbin.com/iTAPeJa/1/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

****Used to this css Define your** `img` tag `vertical-align:middle;` and `h1, h5` define `display:inline-block;` and `vertical-align:initial;`

**As like this**

```
   #wrapper {
display: inline-block;
}

img {
margin-top:2%;vertical-align: middle;
}

h1, h5 {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: initial;
}
```

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7abJB/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
margin-top:2%;
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

h1, h5 {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
}
```